# SSRS: Cannot Change Tab Name when Exporting to Excel

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

Recently I got a problem and wondering if anyone could help.

I have a SSRS report named as 'Processing Quality Report - Source Data'. Normally, when I export it to excel, the excel's tab name should be the same as the report name (Processing Quality Report - Source Data). This time, since the report name is too long for the tab, I want to keep the report name while let the tab show 'Processing Quality_Source Data' (which is short enough for excel to show on tab) as the new tab name.

However, even if I have changed the tablix's Pagename and the report's initialPageName to 'Processing Quality_Source Data', the tab name keeps unchanged on the exported excel, and I don't know why this happens.
Could anyone give me a hint please? Thanks a lot for any help!
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually never used the Initial Page Name before but the Tablix Page Name should be working using the property that the pic shows. I usually don't use a function for static text but it should work.

You can try using the tablix Group to name the page. Highlight the table and then click on the main group in the Grouping window at the bottom.

[image]

Then, in the Properties window, click on the + for Group to expand and enter the Processing Quality_Source Data for the Page Name.

[image]

If it still doesn't work, then check for another table or rectangle that may be embedded in the table or the table is embedded in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Hannover! I tried but it still doesn't work. I changed the report name and the tab name changed with it, I guess some by default page name setting is embed and I haven't found it yet. S

Comment: @Charles916 - when all else fails, you can create a new table and copy the cells from the old one.

Comment: I send the .rdl file to my teammate, then the pagename setting works. I think there must be some other setting on my SSRS that overwrites the pagename. Thanks for your help!